# pass null to c namespace constructor argument for spring

Tags: spring

I'm using the c: and p: namespaces in spring xml configuration files, but how do I pass null in this calls?  I know when NOT using the c: namespace, I can use:

```
<constructor-arg><null/></constructor-arg>
```

but how would I do it for:

```
c:myArgument=?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SpEL for Spring 3 and higher.
I have tested this for p-namespace, but I think, that this decision will work for c-namespace too.

```
<bean ... p:fieldName="#{null}" />
```